# Can I check a condition for one variable

Tags: c

I am writing a program to scan the name, gender, and three monthly checks for a person. Here is an example on what I want entered:

```
Jack m 200 250 300
```

If the user types "Enough" and presses enter without filling the other details I want the loop to end. I tried using two scanf's, one for the string alone and one for the others but it doesn't loop properly. Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
int i;
char names[SIZE][NAME_LEN] = {0}, gender[SIZE] = {0};
int sales[SIZE][SALES_LEN] = {0};
printf("Enter the name, gender and three month sales for name %d: ", i+1);
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++){

    if (strcmp(names[i], "Enough") == 0 || strcmp(names[i], "enough") == 0)
        break;

    scanf("%s %c %d %d %d",names[i], &gender[i], &sales[i][0],&sales[i][1],&sales[i][2]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read and check the first word. Then the rest, if needed... The problem will be with people named "Enough"...

Comment: Step 1) Read user input with `fgets()` and _then_ parse the buffer read.

Comment: yes it was a typo, i ran it and printed out my input to make sure.

Comment: what do you mean by parse the buffer read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is broken is many places: badly ordered statements and wrong kind of reading and parsing. This may do the trick:

```
for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
  char buffer[100]; // A full line
  printf("Enter the name, gender and three month sales for name %d: ", i+1);
  if (fgets(buffer,sizeof buffer,stdin)==NULL // if nothing can be read
      || strncasecmp(buffer,"-stop",5)) {     // or if user typed "-stop" and whatever, an impossible lastname?
    break;
  }
  // try to convert the line into fields of given types...
  if (sscanf(buffer,"%s %c %d %d %d",names[i], &gender[i], &sales[i][0],&sales[i][1],&sales[i][2])!=5) {
    // do something if conversions failed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
while(gets(line)) { ... }
```

If user presses only the return key the gets function returns NULL and the cycle stops. This way the user doesn't have to type "Enough".

*Don't use the gets() function because it's unsafe (risk of buffer overflow).
I usually wrap it in a function which controls the length of the input.